# Is it possible to remove session attribute in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

is it possible in freemarker to remove a session attribue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. FreeMarker is a template engine, and does *not* modify the model in any way.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if the framework within which you are using FreeMarker provides a method or directive for that... or if you add a method yourself that does that. But since FreeMarker is (normally...) used as the View in the MVC paradigm, you shouldn't do that. Creating/removing sessions is the duty of the Controller in MVC. That's the whole point of MVC... separating these concerns.